# Do I need to digitally sign my code for Linux

Tags: linux, code-signing

coming from Windows, I am used to sign my code (.exe, .dll). Especially with the recent Windows versions, executing unsigned code or code signed with a self-signed certificate becomes more and more difficult, if not impossible. I do therefore own a (payed) Authenticode EV certificate and have integrated signing into my build chain.

How important/mandatory is code signing under Linux?

Thnx, Armin.

Comment: Kernel modules can require signing. Users are expected to know what they are running.

Comment: Seriously? Where from? Disassemble the executable and see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is distribution specific, for example in the Debian/Ubuntu ecosystem, the binaries executed are not signed, but the packages usually are. The signature is checked when the package is downloaded by apt. The packages are signed by GPG, so there is no need to buy a certificate from a CA. You distribute your public key to your users so they can check and trust the packages you produce.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this to me, I didn't try yet, but to me it makes sense.